# Nginx get / from /index.php without "directory index is forbidden" elsewhere

Tags: nginx

I need `/` to be shown like `/index.php`.

Right now I have

```
index index.php;
if ( $request_uri = /index.php ) { return 301 /; }
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
```

And everything works fine but there are some errors like

```
directory index of "/home/.../public_html/tmp/" is forbidden
```

which I want to remove. The problem here is `$uri/` in `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden/38046124#38046124

[Ubuntu + Nginx: directory index of "/var/www/app/my-app/" is forbidden](https://serverfault.com/questions/670920/ubuntu-nginx-directory-index-of-var-www-app-my-app-is-forbidden)

But if I change this to `try_files $uri =404;` or `try_files $uri /index.html index.php =404;` then "/" just stops working and shows 404

Why does removing `$uri/` prevent showing index.php if I have `index index.php;`?

How can I set that `/` should check `index.php` and if there is no index.php then just shows 404 without throwing "is forbidden" error?

Comment: Does your website have more than one `index.php` file?

Comment: Maybe there are several but I only care about root `/index.php`. It all works now but with `directory index of "..." is forbidden` when someone hit page that is not here because of `$uri/`.

Answer (score 3):

The `$uri/` term in a `try_files` statement has two distinct purposes.

If the URI does not end with a `/`, but does reference a directory, Nginx will generate a 301 redirection to append a `/`.

If the URI ends with a `/` and references a directory, the Index functionality will be invoked, which can either result in an internal redirection to an index file, or a 403 response if the index file is not found.

One solution to suppressing the 403 response without affecting too many other things is to handle URIs which end with a `/` differently.

For example:

```
location ~ /$ { 
    if (-f ${request_filename}index.php) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1/index.php last;
    }
    return 404;
}
```

The above will test for the existence of `index.php` within the directory, and return 404 if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach might work:

```
location = /index.php {
    return 301 /;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
}
```